# Matrices and Banach algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

If B is an open subset of the complex numbers which contains the closed disc {z $\in$ C: $\vert z \vert \leq \Vert x_o \Vert$} and $f \in H^{\infty}(B)$ (bounded holomorphic functions). Then I need to show that

$ f(x_0)= f \begin{pmatrix}
0  & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
f(0)  & f'(0) & 1/2 f''(0) \\
0 & f(0)  & f'(0) \\
0 & 0 & f(0)
\end{pmatrix} $

If $x_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
0  & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ is in a unital commutative Banach Algebra. I have some trouble getting started though. How would one approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$
around zero. Next if $A$ is a matrix with sufficiently small norm, then 
$$f(A) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}A^n$$
The matrix you are considering is nilpotent - its cube is zero. So just use the formula above.